# Simple html dom - file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto

Tags: php

[image: ERROR]

Im totally done, please help. Im using simple html dom..
Sometimes it successfully do work.

Comment: You should paste more code, otherwise it's impossible to help you without those information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install OpenSSL for PHP correctly. You should also verify that `ssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath` are set.

PS: But really, you should paste your code.